# Good Database with C library?

Tags: c, database

What is a good database with support for C? I want a database that can persist changes when the program is closing and retrieve them when the user starts up the program. I was thinking maybe like SQLite or Berkeley DB. Some documentation would be great too. I just need a database with a library for C. It will be used locally to store simple information like a key (of char *) that corresponds with a value (of char *)

Comment: Are you looking for an embedded db or a remote db ?

Comment: SQLite and Berkeley DB are both native C libraries.... am I missing something?

Comment: When you say "I want a database that can persist changes when the program is closing and retrieve them when the user starts up the program" Does this mean configuration data ? or is the database reading in data manipulating it and then writing it as it goes (CRUD operations) ?

Comment: I think you mean DBMS rather than Database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For embedded data, try SQLite.

Although if it's just program settings for a single instance of the program, an XML file might be your best bet.  There are lots of freely-available XML parsers for C.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL comes with libpq, which is a C library.

Comment: You want to use a full-blown, enterprise-capable database to store program settings?  That's a bit overkill, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to store and retrieve as well as all other criteria one would use to select one of these options.

You can read and write to and from a file.

You can use the databases you mention - They both have excellent documentation and are free.

You can use any open source or commercial RDBMS - Excellent docs also. (MySql PostgresSQL, Firebird, etc ... for open source) (Oracle, DB/2, Sybase, SQLServer, etc ...)

Comment: The question states that the OP wants to store program settings.

Comment: @Robert Harvey -  I want a database that can persist changes when the program is closing and retrieve them when the user starts up the program 
implies to me that he wants to read some info when the program is starting and write it before it closes. I also read it as persisting data while running - I'll ask

Answer (score 0):

For simple tasks you can use: www.simpledatabase.org

```
#include "DB.h"

// Define client structure (register)

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int id;
    char name[60];
    short int age;
} clientSt;

int main() 
{
    // Allocate a client structure 
    clientSt client;

    // Create client database
    db_Create("ClientList.db", sizeof(clientSt));

    // Open client database
    db_Open("ClientList.db", "ClientList");

    // Add client register 1
    client.id = 1;
    strncpy(client.name, "Bob", sizeof(client.name));
    client.age = 38;
    db_CreateRegister((const void*)&client);

    // Add client register 2
    client.id = 2;
    strncpy(client.name, "Alice", sizeof(client.name));
    client.age = 20;
    db_CreateRegister((const void*)&client);

    // Add client register 3
    client.id = 3;
    strncpy(client.name, "John", sizeof(client.name));
    client.age = 25;
    db_CreateRegister((const void*)&client);

    // Print all registers
    db_GoToBegin();
    do
    {
        db_GetRegister(&client);
        printf("ID: %d Name = %s Age = %d\n", client.id, client.name, client.age);
    }while(db_GoToNext() != DB_FALSE);

    // Close database
    db_Close("ClientList");

    // Checks if any error occurred
    if(db_GetError())
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", db_GetErrorMessage());
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: link based answers are usually bad answers, extract some info from this link and then leave URI for reference